# Amount of particle collisions depending on entropy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, entropy, simulations

I'm doing a very simple simulation of random particles. Simple mechanics, elastic collisions. (The simulation is based on a next-event time progression.)

When I count the number of particle particle collisions per simulation time, I observe a significant drop over time. For example, with 10 particles in a $50{\times}50$ box:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{array}{c|c|l}
  \begin{array}{c} \textbf{Time} \\ \left(\text{seconds}\right) \end{array}
& \begin{array}{c} \textbf{Collision Rate} \\ \left(\frac{\text{collisions}}{\text{second}}\right) \end{array}
& \textbf{Notes}
\\ \hline
\phantom{000}3000 & 0.26570 \\ \hline
\phantom{0}100000 & 0.03343 & \text{~70 million pixels traveled} \\ \hline
\phantom{0}200000 & 0.00586 \\ \hline
          1000000 & 0.00095 & \text{~700 million pixels traveled} \\ \hline
          5000000 & 0.00006 \\ \hline
          8000000 & 0.00000
\end{array}
\\[10px]
\textbf{Table 1.}
~\text{Simulated collision rates over time for a}
~50{\times}50
~\text{box.}
\end{array}
$$

So, if the simulation is right, the particles are "avoiding each other" more and more as the entropy rises and finally **maybe** find a configuration to don't collide anymore at all.

I'm adding waves with a frequency based on the current speed of the particles around the particles. As faster the particle as higher the frequency, therefore the interference somehow indicates the probability of collisions. That's the idea (and actually the reason for this simulation.)

Here you see a snapshots of this interference over time:

[image: interference vs time]

Other than I expected the interference gets more accentuated over time. And stays at a kind of similar pattern after some time (this images are from around 2.9E7 seconds):

[image: after]

Any explanation for the drop of collisions? And maybe why the interference gets this pattern? (Or is the simulation flawed?)

Comment: Just curious: Are the added waves created per graph or 1 per graph + kept in memory for $n$ steps? (Or, does the interference pattern has memory of past positions?)

Comment: Welcome to SE.Physics!  I tried to $\mathrm{\TeX}\text{-up}$ your table; I hope I interpreted it correctly.  Please feel free to [edit] anything to make any fixes!

Comment: Yeah, dunno what's going on with your simulation, but that at least looks off.  As the simulation runs, your particles should eventually approach some equilibrium dynamics, which may differ from the startup behavior as your initial placements may not be a fair selection of an equilibrium state.  Still, you shouldn't come to a situation in which particles avoid each other, unless your parameters are such that the equilibrium behavior is merely that they barely ever collide and the apparent lack of collisions is a mis-observation due to insufficient observation time for the equilibrium behavior.

Comment: Anywho, do you have some basic physical parameters for this system?  They'd seem useful in calculating the expected equilibrium collision rate that you should be observing.